# Multiple sites/default folders

Tags: 8, configuration

I have a Drupal 8 website on Docker containers. Drupal sites folders contains, besides the *default* folder, two folders, the *settings.php* file, and configuration.

The goal is to have different configuration inside each folder (inside each settings.php) and connected to same or different database.

Because client wants only one instance of Drupal (a single set of containers), how can I manage the website to change symlink from the *default* folder to each folders with different configurations?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to set up a multisite. You may want to start [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/multisite-drupal/set-up-a-multisite).

Answer (score 2):

sites/sites.php is the file that allows to define a set of aliases that map hostnames, ports, and pathnames to configuration directories in the sites directory